# Next-auth: Props to page undefined although passed from getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to pass the session I get from `getSession` (using `next-auth`) as props to a page. I know I can use `useSession()` within the component but according to my understanding this should work as well and I don't understand why it doesn't.

This seems to be a similar problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605307/nextjs-pass-props-from-getserversideprops-to-children-components) but there is no answer.

Here's my very basic `pages/settings.tsx`:

```
import { Card, CardContent, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { User } from "@prisma/client";
import { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from "next";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

interface SettingsProps {
  user: User,
}

const Settings : NextPage<SettingsProps> = ({user})=>{
  // in here, user is always undefined...
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent>      
        <Typography variant="h3">Settings</Typography>
        <Typography>UserId: {user.id}</Typography>
        <Typography>Created: {(new Date(user.createdAt)).toLocaleDateString()}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      
    </Card>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<SettingsProps> =  async (context) =>{
  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  console.log(session.user); // this works and logs the user

  return {
    props: { user: session.user },
  };
};

export default Settings;
```

I have augmented the `next-auth` Session type like so (`types/next-auth.d.ts`):

```
import { User } from "@prisma/client";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    user: User
  }
}
```

According to my understanding of React and NextJs the code above should work flawlessly, but when visiting the page I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
  13 |       <CardContent>      
  14 |         <Typography variant="h3">Settings</Typography>
> 15 |         <Typography>UserId: {user.id}</Typography>
     |                                  ^
  16 |         <Typography>Created: {(new Date(user.createdAt)).toLocaleDateString()}</Typography>
  17 |       </CardContent>
  18 |
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I've run into the same thing and I'm clueless as to how to proceed further.

Comment: I was not. I used the [`useSession` hook](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession), which does not return the user on the first render but then works like a charm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, and resolved it through pure luck.

It seems that Next.js, through its pageProps, makes use of the `session` prop in pages. So when we're trying to pass `session` directly from `getServerSideProps`, it is undefined for some reason on the client component.

In short, just return the user from `session`, or rename the session variable to something else.

This is the patten I'm using across the app wherever I need SSR auth protection:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
  const session = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
  const user = session?.user;

  if (!user) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      user,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Wow -- great find. This fix worked for me. I've been scratching my head over this one for the last couple of hours!

Answer (score 0):

Although everything looks good for me if you have a user object in session and an id in the user object, as you mentioned early. So, you can use [optional changing.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
<Typography variant="h3">Settings</Typography>
 <Typography>UserId: {user?.id}</Typography>
```

Comment: Adding optional chaining did fix the TypeError but did not resolve the problem, since then it does not show anything as the `userId` (and "invalid date" for the createdAt date) - `user` is simply `undefined` forever.

Comment: You mentioned, console.log(session.user); // this works and logs the user. Did you have id, createdAt on user object ?

Comment: Yes, this logs `{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Taxel',
  email: null,
  createdAt: '2022-02-17T15:08:46.476Z',
  isAdmin: true
}`

Answer (score 0):

[nextauth docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#extend-default-interface-properties)
`interface {user: User & DefaultSession['user']}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).